# az devops security permission for Servicehook

Tags: azure, azure-devops, command-line-interface

We have users that need permission to create servicehooks as part of a PR integration.
The users create PAT with permissions: Code (read & write) and service connection (read, query & manage).
It works seamlessly for users with Project Administrator permissions, but we don't want to set this for all.
How can we allocate just the specific permissions needed to create the servicehooks?

I would assume the Namespace ID for ServiceHooks: cb594ebe-87dd-4fc9-ac2c-6a10a4c92046
But as an Project admin, I get access denied when trying to add allow-bit for a group on a repository calling this namespace.

How can we achieve this?

az devops security permission show --id cb594ebe-87dd-4fc9-ac2c-6a10a4c92046 --subject (group-ID) --token (token to repo)

Error:
Access Denied: (some ID) needs the following permission(s) on the resource (the repo)
to perform this action: View Subscriptions

Would expect to see the permissions, as my user is project admin.

Comment: You must be a member of the Project Collection Administrators security group to run the Security permission commands, if you have project admin access it's for only project level not for Org level,  check the [Ms Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/organizations/security/manage-tokens-namespaces?view=azure-devops#prerequisites) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

To view and edit subscriptions of Service Hooks in a project, the users should have the "**`Edit subscriptions`**" and "**`View subscriptions`**" permissions. By default, only PA (**Project Administrators**) have these permissions. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/overview?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Forganizations%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops#faqs).

The two permissions cannot be set on the web UI of Azure DevOps. To grant them to other users directly, need PCA (**Project Collection Administrators**) to run the '[**az devops security permission**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/devops/security/permission?view=azure-cli-latest)' CLI or [**Security REST API**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/security/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1).

PCA are the organization level administrators. PA are the project level administrators. Since running these security related CLI/API is Azure DevOps organization level operations, only PCA can do this. PA do not have the access. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/manage-tokens-namespaces?view=azure-devops#prerequisites).

---

To use the security related CLI to grant the "**`Edit subscriptions`**" and "**`View subscriptions`**" permissions to other users, you can run the following commands:

1. below command can get the **`namespace-id`** of **`ServiceHooks`** is '**`cb594ebe-87dd-4fc9-ac2c-6a10a4c92046`**'.

   ```bash
   az devops security permission namespace list --org https://dev.azure.com/{Organization Name} --output table
   ```
2. Run below command to show the details of permissions available in **`ServiceHooks`** namespace.

   ```bash
   az devops security permission namespace show --namespace-id cb594ebe-87dd-4fc9-ac2c-6a10a4c92046 --output table
   ```
3. Run below command to lists the tokens for **`ServiceHooks`** namespace and associated with the specified user **`{Email Address}`**.

   ```bash
   az devops security permission list --id cb594ebe-87dd-4fc9-ac2c-6a10a4c92046 --subject {Email Address} --output table
   ```
4. Run below command to show the permissions for the specified token, the **`ServiceHooks`** namespace and the specified user.

   ```bash
   az devops security permission show --id cb594ebe-87dd-4fc9-ac2c-6a10a4c92046 --subject {Email Address} --token {token} --output table
   ```
5. Run below commands to grant specified user the "**`Edit subscriptions`**" and "**`View subscriptions`**" permissions.

   ```bash
   az devops security permission update --allow-bit 1 --id cb594ebe-87dd-4fc9-ac2c-6a10a4c92046 --subject {Email Address} --token {token} --output table
   az devops security permission update --allow-bit 2 --id cb594ebe-87dd-4fc9-ac2c-6a10a4c92046 --subject {Email Address} --token {token} --output table
   ```

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

Comment: @HeddaDAsperheim, Is there any update from you? Have tried the steps mentioned in my answer to use Azure DevOps CLI to set the permissions of Service Hooks subscriptions? I'd like to know whether the answer work for you.